# Store value in list when looping a dictionary

Tags: python

I wish to store the value inside a list. Let my code explain:

```
s = []
for i, x in enumerate(:something:):
    if ......:
        s.append()
    store = []
    elif x["some"] == :againsomething:
        store.append(x["value"]) // here it will store the output one by one.
```

Here my output is:

```
["Man"]
["Eater"]
```

My expected store in list "stored":

```
["Man", "Eater"]
```

Both are strings and stored in a separate list but I wanted it to be stored in the form ["Man", "Eater"]. I know I can just store it in list "s". However, due to certain reasons, I still have functions I need to write and rules inside it so I can't store it in this list "s". Is there a way to append it according to my expected output in list "store" instead of list "s"?

Update:I also know we can do it this way:

```
s = []
for i, x in enumerate(:something:):
    if ......:
        s.append()
store = [x["value"] for i,x in enumerate(:something:) if ....]
```

But I do not want to create another list comprehension outside of this loop due to the index format running away.

Comment: Do you want the value of only the last iteration in the Store[] list while S[] will hold the values of all the iterations of the for loop? If not you need to declare Store[] outside of the loop.

Comment: Please at least give valid code if you want people to help.  `s.append()` is invalid for a list.  And, who knows what your `:something:` is?  Can you just give a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to demonstrate your problem?

Answer (score 1):

Your question is a bit confusing.  The last bit of code helps.  From that code, it seems like maybe you just want this:

Ok, responding to your comment, here's a way to still store in a list, but preserve the index value along with the main value.  You now just have a "tuple" (acts just like a list) that keeps the two together.

```
s = []
store = []
for i, x in enumerate(:something:):
    if ......:
        s.append()
    if x["some"] == :againsomething:
        store.append((i, x["value"]))
```

This would let you do the iteration again, but just on what's in 
'store', like this:

```
for i, valueofx in store:
   ... use i and valueofx ...
```

So far, I see no reason to use a map

Comment: Yes, I knew this is one of the methods too but I do not know how to preserve the index value. May instead of making the "store" as list, I should make it into dictionary "store" and then include the index value for each x["value"] inside. Any good recommendation?

Comment: Thank you so much sir and I will try it now.

Comment: If what you need to write is a comment, but you don't have the reputation for writing comment yet, then please just don't write.  Writing an answer is not a proper "workaround" for that.  There are reason behind how things works in StackOverflow.

Comment: Ha.  I updated my answer, and it took away the vote.  I hadn't notice S.O. do that before.  No biggie, but feel free to vote up my new answer, where I just took out the initial bit about the answer being a work in progress.

Comment: Well, @Adrian, I'm always into feedback.  But it's helpful if you actually read what is put in the answer before you comment on it and get it wrong.  I didn't say I didn't have the reputation to add a comment.  I said that I wanted to present some code to the OP, and you can't put code in a comment such that it's readable.  If you would be so kind as to give me the official S.O. way to deal with that effectively, I'll certainly follow that in the future.  Otherwise, I got the OP the answer he was looking for.  What's the problem if that's the result?

Comment: If I understand what you're asking, I don't think this is a problem.  Note that in the example I gave you for iterating the second time, we aren't using an iteration.  So we're not using the new place in the list...we're using the index from the ORIGINAL list.  This is what you wanted, yes?

Comment: @Steve: oh sorry I misread the reason you are not writing comment.  However, still, in SO we still shouldn't use an Answer for discussion to "work it out" with questioner.  Anyway, I think the question is poorly asked and OP has the obligation to refine it :)

Comment: @Adrian, apology accepted.  So respectfully, what's the alternative?  Trying to prod the OP into writing the code you have in your head seems very arduous.  But I'll certainly consider that next time.  Didn't see a problem, but I do kinda get your point.

Comment: @slacklikehellking9, I realiuze that you're saying you want to preserve where you put the answer in 's' rather than where it came from in the original list, right? The problem with this is that you aren't always putting the value in 's'.  If you want to store, say, -1 in the 'store' list if you didn't put it in 's', you could do that.  When you did store it in 's', its index is (len(s)-1).

Comment: @Steve: Usually I will just give comment on what is unclear and insufficient for the question, and leave it for OP to clean that up.  Just note that SO is not a forum, so having an answer for back-and-fro discussion is kind of against the philosophy of SO.   IMHO, we should teach OP how to ask question, instead of having discussion to dig out what's in his mind :)

Comment: I totally agree with you now @Adrian.  I've never done this before (had a back and forth with the OP), so I'm learning by doing right now.  I totally get you (so I'll stop now) - BTW, maybe you can help me with another S.O. do/don't.  Notice that I tried to refer to you without using your full username.  Is there an official way to reference a username with a space in it? (you know how much we programmers hate spaces)

Comment: Great to know. Though I was commenting on the approach, I do really appreciate your passion and helpfulness in helping OP :)  For referring user name, afaik, SO's comment will prompt out the suggested name for you for the first time you typed "@", and from my experience, for username containing name, it just remove the spaces.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188856/discussion-between-steve-and-adrian-shum).